# What exactly is a Docker repository?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I can't seem to find a definition of exactly what is a Docker repository.  The general approach to labelling seems to be username/imagename.

Of course, it contains Docker images BUT do they need to be different versions of the same image or can they be different Docker images?

For example, could I keep App1, App2, ... in the same Docker repository and just use labels to distinguish them.

Comment: Just to be pedantic; repositories store _images_, not _containers_.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianMouat you are right. I was sloppy in my use of language. I have edited and corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is that a Docker Repository is a labelled set of versions of an image.

Although it seems technically possible for them to be semantically different images, the difference perhaps being denoted by the label, this will be 1) confusing because they all have the same image name (confusing for humans and software that uses the images), and 2) not in line with the intended use of the repositories as far as I can tell, and 3) probably in opposition to the business model for the Docker Hub hosted registry for public and private repositories.

It was never my intention to attempt to break that business model, I was just confused somewhat since the term repository often means something more general than just a single conceptual entity. Docker provides the ability to privately host your own registries, that contain many repositories.

Comment: It would have helped if the docker docs had recommended that a repository should contain only 1 Dockerfile. Then explained that the repository refers to all the different images (versions) built from that Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

By convention the Docker images are named as `<owner>/<application>:<tag>`. There is not any technical restriction if you want to keep different applications under the same repository (i.e.: there doesn't has to be related different tags unless you force that relation), and you can have, for example, `mycompany/myuser:app1` and `mycompany/myuser:app2`. But this is not the way you will found most of the public images which are tagged as I indicated before.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the only problem is there is only one "latest", so we would have to specifically indicate label for each container.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Docker Doc](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#share-your-image),

> A registry is a collection of repositories, and a repository is a collection of images – sort of like a GitHub repository, except the code is already built.
>
> The notation for associating a local image with a repository on a registry, is 
>   username/repository:tag.
>
> The :tag is optional, but recommended; it’s the mechanism that registries use to give Docker images a version. So, putting all that together, enter your username, and repo and tag names, so your existing image will upload to your desired destination:
>
> `docker tag friendlyhello username/repository:tag`

I also find using the word *repository* a bit confusing in that context. In the end, the repository is meant to contain all the versions of an image, with the tag *latest* used to designate the image which will be pulled in case no tag is specified when using the *docker pull* command.